# Sublime Text 2, Tab Key removes selection on single line (instead of indenting)

Tags: sublimetext2

(Google turns up this http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=14005 but that answer isn't satisfactory to me)

In Sublime Text 2, when you hit tab:

- If you have nothing selected it will add a tab (or spaces) at your cursor location. This is good.
- If you have multiple lines selected it will indent them all. This is good.
- If you have a selection within a single line it will replace this text with a tab. This isn't BAD exactly, but it's not what I want. I'd rather it indents that line, as with multiple lines selected.

I'd think the way to do this would be to create a keyboard shortcut that activates if you have text selected when you hit tab, that "command": "indent"s, but I can't figure out how to say "if you have text selected". The keymap documentation seems to be somewhere between impenetrable and nonexistent....

Does anyone know how to get Sublime Text 2 to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth noting that if you select text that doesn't include a newline with multiple cursors it replaces the text with a tab.

With that in mind, putting this in my keymap does what I want:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "indent", "context":
    [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ! It works fine. Additionaly, you should want the same principle for unindent (shift+tab) :

```
{ "keys": ["shift+tab"], "command": "unindent", "context":
    [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ah good point. I personally prefer shift+tab to always unindent regardless of context, but if you don't this is helpful :)